# dplyr: Return number of distinct values from of all columns of a filtered dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't find an example of how to do this in Dplyr anywhere, but surely it can be done?

Example dataframe:

```
x      y      z
this   it     1
that   them   2
that   us     3
that   you    4
```

Aiming for something like this:

```
data %>%
  filter(x %in% 'that') %>%
  summarise(n_distinct(all dataframe cols))
```

To return this:

```
x  y  z
1  3  3
```

It works if you reference just one column, but how do you return the number of distinct values for all columns without calling `n_distinct` on each column individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the scoped variants of `summarise` and `mutate`, appending `_all`, `_at`, `_if`.

```
 data.frame(x = c("this", "that", "that", "that"),
            y = c("it", "them","us","you"),
            z = c(1,2,3,4),
            stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  filter(x %in% "that") %>%
  summarise_all(n_distinct)
```

Comment: That's even better!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I worked it out using `summarise_all`.

```
data %>%
  filter(x %in% 'that') %>%
  summarise_all(funs(n_distinct(.)))
```

Comment: Did you just answer your own question?